# P5 — Fixed Random positions with an animated GIF

Tags: javascript, animation, layout, processing, p5.js

I am having trouble with a sketch that uses animated GIF. I want to setup a random layout that can be modified with a mouse press. This layout then should play the animated give on the given coordinates by the initial setup. The issue is that these positions keep being changed by the drawn and I cannot figure it out how to have the random coordinates and the give playing on those.

How can I set up this random layout and play the gif on the set coordinates? Thank you in advance.

**Pseudo-code**

- Setup multiple random coordinates for the layout
- Animated the GIF within the inial layout coordinates
- Press mouse to randomise the layout

**Sketch**

[CodeSanBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fragments-new-3noqs?file=/src/index.js:0-3002)

**Code**

```
import "./styles.css";
import p5 from "p5";

// img = sketch.loadImage(`http://placeimg.com/640/360/people`);

let myp5 = new p5((sketch) => {
  var img;
  var settings;
  var src_x,
    src_y,
    src_width,
    src_height,
    dist_x,
    dist_y,
    dist_width,
    dist_height,
    dist_scale,
    step;

  let count = 25;
  p5.disableFriendlyErrors = true;
  var layout;

  sketch.preload = () => {
    // img = sketch.loadImage("https://source.unsplash.com/random");
    img = sketch.loadImage("../assets/02.gif");
    // img = sketch.createImg("../assets/02.gif");
  };

  sketch.setup = () => {
    sketch.createCanvas(sketch.int(img.width), sketch.int(img.height));
    sketch.angleMode(sketch.DEGREES);
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      makeRandomn(img);
    }
    // createLayout(img);
  };

  function makeRandomn(gif) {
    sketch.background(gif);
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      src_width = sketch.random(gif.width / 50, gif.width / 5);
      src_height = sketch.random(gif.height / 50, gif.height / 5);

      src_x = sketch.random(0, gif.width - src_width);
      src_y = sketch.random(0, gif.height - src_height);

      step = sketch.random(gif.width / 100, gif.width / 20);

      dist_x = src_x + sketch.random(-step, step);
      dist_y = src_y + sketch.random(-step, step);

      dist_scale = sketch.random(0.5, 1.5);
      dist_width = src_width * dist_scale;
      dist_height = src_height * dist_scale;

      let gif_trim = gif.get(src_x, src_y, src_width, src_height);

      sketch.push();
      sketch.translate(dist_x + dist_width / 2, dist_y + dist_height / 2);
      sketch.rotate(sketch.random(90) * (sketch.random(100) > 50 ? -1 : 1));
      sketch.imageMode(sketch.CENTER);
      sketch.image(gif_trim, 0, 0, dist_width, dist_height);
      sketch.image(gif_trim, 0, 0);
      sketch.pop();
    }

    // sketch.noLoop();
    settings = {
      src_x: src_x,
      src_y: src_y,
      src_width: src_width,
      src_height: src_height,
      dist_x: dist_x,
      dist_y: dist_y,
      dist_width: dist_width,
      dist_height: dist_height
    };
  }

  function createLayout(gif) {
    sketch.background(gif);

    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      const {
        src_x,
        src_y,
        src_width,
        src_height,
        dist_x,
        dist_y,
        dist_width,
        dist_height
      } = settings;

      let gif_trim = gif.get(src_x, src_y, src_width, src_height);

      sketch.push();
      sketch.translate(dist_x + dist_width / 2, dist_y + dist_height / 2);
      sketch.rotate(sketch.random(90) * (sketch.random(100) > 50 ? -1 : 1));
      sketch.imageMode(sketch.CENTER);
      sketch.image(gif_trim, 0, 0, dist_width, dist_height);
      sketch.image(gif_trim, 0, 0);
      sketch.pop();
    }
    // sketch.noLoop();
  }

  sketch.draw = () => {
    // createLayout(img);
    makeRandomn(img);
  };

  sketch.mousePressed = () => {
    console.log(settings);
  };
});

// let myp5 = new p5(s, "p5sketch");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is draw and mousePressed. Draw is filled with makeRandom( ); So every frame a new random location is picked. If you click and settings is called, the only thing that happens is the coordinates are reassigned. But draw is run again and the mouse click is essentially passed over. You want instead for makeRandom to be called on a mouse press.